# Fontawesome plugin ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

Someone already tried to make the fontawesome plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/fontawesome) working with the ckeditor module on Drupal 7 ?

I followed the whole installation (modified the ckeditor.config.js, downloaded the needed plugins as well) but the button still doesn't appear even if the plugin is checked on the appearance configuration.

Do I need to write a hook_ckeditor_plugin in my own module ?

Thanks guys!